# Object assign with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, object, merge, lodash, assign

I have this `initialState` in my Redux store:

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching : false,
  active     : {}
}
```

Where `active` is an object.

Now I have an action that *should* append or add a property to `active`’s `data` property, like so:

```
[DASHBOARD_TEMPLATE_DATA_RECEIVE]: (state, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      isFetching   : false,
      active       : Object.assign({}, active, {data[action.key]: action.data})
    })
}
```

As you can see, `data[action.key]` is not permitted. How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with this:

```
active: Object.assign({}, active, {
  data: Object.assign({}, data, {
    [action.key]: action.data
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the object up first, making use of square bracket notation to use a string as a property name:

```
var data = {};
data[action.key] = action.data;
```

then use that newly created object:

```
[DASHBOARD_TEMPLATE_DATA_RECEIVE]: (state, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      isFetching   : false,
      active       : Object.assign({}, active, data)
    })
}
```

Comment: I think it should be:

`active : Object.assign({}, active, { data })`

Comment: @JoeyHipolito, perhaps if that is something specific to Redux, for which im not familiar. But in vanilla javascript, `data` is already an object, so no need to surrpound it with `{}`.

Comment: In-fact, ```data[action.key] = action.data;``` was way helpful if we want to add multiple nodes before hand. Thanks @Jamiec

Answer (score 1):

I would guess a computed property name might work.

Untested:

```
active: Object.assign({}, active, {[data[action.key]]: action.data})
```